# File is not created, but it works

Tags: c++, file

I want to make a project using file repository, but I have a problem that it doesn't create the file which I read from the console. What should I do so it will also create the file?

```
int FileRepository::addDog(const Dog& dog)
{
    if (this->findDog(dog.getName()) != -1)
        return -1; 
    std::ofstream fout;

    //cout << dog<<"\n";
    //cout << this->fileName;

    fout.open(this->fileName.c_str(), std::ios_base::app);
    fout << dog;
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outputStream,const Dog& dog)
{
    outputStream << dog.name << ", " << dog.breed << ", " << dog.birthDate << ", " << dog.numberOfShots << ", " << dog.photo <<'\n';
    return outputStream;
}
```

The commented lines are printing fine. this->fileName would be the full path of that file. For example if i give the desktop path, I don't see any new text file, but the program passed the uni online tests.

One university test looks like:

```
fileLocation C:\tmp\GamifyCs\gpie2724\Files and tests\e01364e3-f98c-4348-bdb6-1ec7d611d5c7\add+list.txt

mode A

add 123, abc, 01-01-2000, 456, def

list

exit File contents:
123, abc, 01-01-2000, 456, def
```

Comment: please add a question and a [mcve]

Comment: You need to check that opening the file actually worked: `if(std::ofstream fout(fileName, std::ios_base::app); fout) { success... } else { error.... }`

Comment: But if it can't find that file, shouldn't it create it at that given path?

Comment: If you have permission to, yes. Always check if opening a file succeeds.